# Is there a method, that NavigationLink won't show elements, that are not from "today"

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to add a feature to simple calories tracking app.
So the app helps count calories consumed throughout the day.

At the moment this code is responsible for the list of food consumed:

```
                List {
                    ForEach(food) { food in
                        NavigationLink(destination: EditFoodView(food: food)) {
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                                    Text(food.name!)
                                        .bold()
            
                                    Text("\(Int(food.calories))") + Text(" calories").foregroundColor(.red)
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(calcTimeSince(date: food.date!))
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .italic()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteFood)
                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
```

As you can see the list shows all the food that is stored in database (CoreData).

Is there a way to make the list to list only food from "today"??

[image]

Comment: Yes. Alter your fetch request so that it only retrieves data where the timestamp matches your requirement. You could also filter the data after the fetch, but that seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: Look into NSPredicate

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690554